# Difference between Shape Groups and normal Groups in Sketch?

Tags: vector, shapes, sketch-app

I noticed that there are two different types of grouping/nesting in Sketch, one is a Shape Group and other is a normal Group denoted by a folder.

[image]

What's the difference? And how do I create a Shape Group? I've only encountered them by importing SVGs exported by Illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A group in the sidebar denoted by a folder icon is just that - a group. This is organizational concept.

You create it by selecting several shapes and grouping them by clicking `Group` icon. Since this is organizational concept, you can't apply shape's action to it, like masking, shadows, etc.

---

A group in the sidebar denoted by a shape icon is just that - a shape, just consisting of several sub-shapes. This is graphical concept.

You create it by selecting several shapes and unionizing them by clicking `Union` icon. Since this is a shape by itself, you can apply all of the properties of a regular shape to it - masking, shadows, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Sketch is treating these Illustrator groups as a combined shape.

Select any two shapes, Layers > Combine > Union

Then, in the Layers List, click on icon and set to None.

[image]